# yarn run build dist - TypeError: Cannot set property constructor of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: node.js, typescript, github, npm

I am getting this error after running this command in a GitHub workflow:
`npm-run-all -p types transpile`

```
@internal_package: $ swc src --out-dir dist
@internal_package: /home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/loadTypescript.js:13
@internal_package:         function __() { this.constructor = d; }
@internal_package:                                          ^
@internal_package: TypeError: Cannot set property constructor of [object Object] which has only a getter
@internal_package:     at new __ (/home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/loadTypescript.js:13:42)
@internal_package:     at __extends (/home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/loadTypescript.js:14:84)
@internal_package:     at /home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/loadTypescript.js:65:5
@internal_package:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/repo-name/repo-name/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/loadTypescript.js:100:2)
@internal_package:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
@internal_package:     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
@internal_package:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
@internal_package:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
@internal_package:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
@internal_package:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
@internal_package: Node.js v18.17.1
```

I've tried to bump the node version to 18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by bumping the version of `ttypescript` from 1.5.13 to 1.5.15